# c# Class inheritence, which ID is this setting?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, class-design

```
/// <summary>
/// Holds data associated with a label
/// </summary>
public class ArtworkDataLabel : ArtworkLabel
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public ArtworkDataLabel()
    {
        this.ID = 5;
    }
}    

/// <summary>
/// A template label
/// </summary>
public class ArtworkLabel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    snip
}
```

This confuses me, why is the compiler allowing this, and which ID is being set?  How do I diferentiate between ID's?  Should I  be renaming one of the ID's to something else?

Comment: Do you really need *both* IDs? If so, aren't they different things? What's the difference? That may help pick better names. If they're the same, you only need one.

Comment: I find it useful to always compile with the "treat warnings as errors" flag on; I believe that would stop you from doing things such as this =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are hiding the property in the base class, implicitly using the new operator:

`public new int ID { get; set; }`

Which overrides the method.

Answer (score 2):

It hides the base class' member and sets the child class' ID.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find if you build it that you have warning which indicates you have one member which 'hides', or 'shadows' another, but I don't think (by default, at least) it will flag up as a hard compiler error.

To enable this scenario so there is no confusion, you should mark the ID property in the base class as 'virtual', and in the subclass you 'override' it:

```
public class ArtworkDataLabel : ArtworkLabel
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public override int ID { get; set; }

    public ArtworkDataLabel()
    {
        this.ID = 5;
    }
}    

public class ArtworkLabel
{
    public virtual  int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what happens here is that the `ID` declared in `ArtworkDataLabel` *hides* the `ID` declared in `ArtworkLabel`. If you check visual studio, you'll see that this generates a *warning*. If you intend to *hide* the that property, you can use the `new` keyword as follows:

```
public new int ID {get;set;}
```

here's [an article](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Basic_Concepts%E2%80%94Hiding_through_Inheritance) that explains this feature in more detail.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

ArtwordDataLabel.ID hides ArtworkLabel.ID and you should be seeing a compiler warning you that this is happening and that you should use "new" to indicate that this is intentional.  It's really easy to observe the behavior by changing the properties back to traditional properties and including some trace logging.

I think the bigger question here though is whether inheritance is the right structure for these classes.  Depending on what you're trying to do with these classes you may find that using the decorator pattern or even keeping them completely separate is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should rename them or use the 'new' [modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier). The ID that you're getting is always the one in the inheriting class, not the parent's.